# Exporting Large Amounts of Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, export, report, out-of-memory

Here is my issue..

We have 2 types of reports in our site, data shown in grid and data instantly downloaded as a report.

These reports can contain a few years of data (1+ million rows), we have been allowing our customers to download the data against a date range, but we have started limited how long they can view data to prevent performance issues in our site. However, the data is still getting pretty large even on a small date range, now that they are expanding, and if they download too much, our memory spikes over a few gigs and run out of memory.

Question I have is, I rather not limit their data so I'm trying to figure out a good solution to allow them to download as much as they want.

I can limit what they see by only returning data per page so there is no performance issues, however downloading is always the problem.

I've looked into async but haven't successfully been able to get that to work, as it spikes the memory when I'm loading the data.

Ideas? Thoughts? Suggestions?

Code Example:

```
// Get Data

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

con.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString";
con.Open();

cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProc";
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);

con.Close();

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dg.DataBind();
dg.RenderControl(htw);

Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls");
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

When I run this with my data.. which is approximately 800k rows, my memory spikes and I get an out of memory error, and make things worse.. it always hogs up at the RenderControl until its done

Comment: Why not just throw hardware at the problem and add a few more RAM sticks? They're pretty cheap these days.

Comment: That is not an option, can't just increase ram because of memory issues, especially since the reports usually spike up to 4GB

Answer (score 2):

i'm assuming the data comes from a backend database. If so, you should not have the user wait for this operation to complete. It is a bad UI design, esp when the memory can go upto 4GB.

I agree with the other suggestions that you should look into improving your code and design probably to help reduce the footprint. But regardless, you should have something like a scheduled job architecture for this.

You let the user to hit download on a search/file and it gets added to a queue in a database table. There is a db/.net process that comes along and processes these jobs and generate a file in the proper format on the server. It may be possible to reuse the file across many users if the data is the same and you use proper naming conventions. The user should then be able to go to a download queue page and see all his downloads that he has scheduled. Once complete, he will be able to download the file.

if you have a requirement that will not let you do this, please put a comment explaining it.

Comment: This is one idea I had in the back of my mind, but still trying to figure out how to get the data, since it hoses up trying to get the data, so I'd have to just send the criteria or what the user is wanting, so the 3rd party job can pull instead of the website

Comment: There is a difference between the web site doing this and another server executing the job. Web site will either timeout or make it a very painful experience. What you can do is to implement kind of like a paging in the db and only bring back chunks of 100k or so and update the file in sequence.

Comment: it may sound like too much work, but once you take one step at a time, it will be simple and you will be proud at the end :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here we go:

- DONT USE A TABLE
- DONT USE A DATASET

Finished.

Get a data reader, write the HTML as you go - you never keep all the data in memory. Your approach never will scale.

Comment: Just to add to this, using a table means you have to load all that data into memory, then during the render all that data gets copied into the output, so you've now got 2 copies in memory. Even using a datareader would help by reducing the amount of data loaded into memory.

Comment: Plus you dont ahve to cache the output - you can stream it out. Datatables are bad in msot cases, bu t for rendering hugh amounts of data this turns insanely bad.

Answer (score 0):

Can you rewrite the stored procedure to be paged and loop through the dataset? Then rewrite the output portion to stream the file instead of outputting it all in one go (your current method is basically just writing out an HTML table).

Paging the data will keep the download process from storing all of that data in memory

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!!

Same problem was face by me when i was working on  Exporting Large Amounts of Data in Excel.

solution : you can use open XMl dll to solve your problem.
using this dll you can export large amount of data in excel and memory consumption will also be less.

more information you can get from here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Here's another stack overflow solution on Open XML  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370672/export-a-large-data-query-60k-rows-to-excel/42304339#42304339